# How to scale one side of image

Tags: gimp

I know how to scale the width and height of an image in gimp. However I just want to change the width of one side of an image without changing the height. Is there any way to do this because whenever I change the width of an image in the "Scale Image" window it automatically changes the height. I am trying to only change the image width so I can change the image ration to 2:1 so it fits a requirement.

Comment: Hi user65880, Welcome to GD.SE! Can you tell us what you've tried? Are you trying to change the canvas dimensions or the image resolution? FYI, if you only edit one of the dimensions without keeping the ratio then your image will be distorted. Anyways if you're changing the image width only then you will have to **unlink** the width and height before you change the size.

Comment: @AndrewH How do I unlink the width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the "Chain" icon between the Width and Height boxes to unlink the two properties. This allows you to change the Width and Height properties independently.

NOTE: If you only edit one of the dimensions without keeping the ratio then your image will be distorted. If you want to keep the image ratio the same but still change the width of the image then you will need to change the canvas size.